# how to fill in NAs using difference between distances

Tags: r, dataframe, distance, na

I have a dataframe where I am looking at the distance different individuals travel over 4 hours (simplified version below). In some cases, the distance has not been recorded and so the value of the distance column is NA.

```
ID<-rep(c("x1","x2"),each=4)
dist<-c(1,3,NA,6,1,NA,NA,7)
time<-rep(c(1,2,3,4), times=2)
data<-data.frame(ID,dist)
data
ID times dist
x1     1    1
x1     2    3
x1     3   NA
x1     4    6
x2     1    1
x2     2   NA
x2     3   NA
x2     4    7
```

I want to replace those NA values so the individual covers distances of equal length between two known distances in the case of multiple NA's, or the average distance between two known distances in the case of a single NA.
Here's what the dataframe would look like:

```
dist2<-c(1,3,4.5,6,1,3,5,7)
data2<-data.frame(ID,times,dist2)
data2
ID times dist
x1     1    1
x1     2    3
x1     3   4.5
x1     4    6
x2     1    1
x2     2    3
x2     3    5
x2     4    7
```

Any thoughts? I was trying out creating a for loop or a function, but I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `na.approx` function from the `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)    
data$dist = na.approx(data$dist)
data

  ID dist
1 x1  1.0
2 x1  3.0
3 x1  4.5
4 x1  6.0
5 x2  1.0
6 x2  3.0
7 x2  5.0
8 x2  7.0
```

In your example, the NAs only occur in positions 2 or 3, but in case you have `NA`s at the first or last position for a user, you may want to wrap `na.approx` in a `group_by` call:

```
library(dplyr)
data = data %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
mutate(dist = na.approx(dist))
```